# Facebook Multi Friend Selector Dialog failure?

Tags: facebook

I am getting the following error when I press "Send Request" on my facebook multi friend selector dialog.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php#cb=f13538d5d4&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fjoincrowdy.com%2Ff3b62245cc&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=f145be71f&result=%7B%22request%22%3A%22271624056256532%22%2C%22to%22%3A[%22122614229%22]%2C%22updated_frictionless%22%3Afalse%7D from frame with URL http://MYAPP.com/rooms/1. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I originally was developing on myapp.com:3000 but this error prompted me to try sending app request via production mode (port 80). That did not solve the issue.

NOTE: I added 127.0.0.1 myapp.com in my /etc/hosts Will that result in this error?

This is my code:

```
function initFb() { 
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : user.fbAppId, 
      frictionlessRequests: true, 
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    });
    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
}

function attachInviteButton() { 
  $("#invite").click(sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector);
}

function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests', 
    message: 'Invite your friends to play now.',
  }, requestCallback);
}

function requestCallback() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the JavaScript [SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) you'll see that when they call the *FB.init* they provide a channel url:

```
FB.init({
    appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
    channelUrl: '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
    status: true, // check login status
    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
});
```

Which you have not.
In the same page, under the *Channel File* section there's an explanation of what it's good for and how to supply it.

It says clearly:

> The channel file addresses some issues with cross domain communication
>   in certain browsers

This solution **might** fix that problem for you.